# Sklearn OrdinalEncoder Parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For sklearn OrdinalEncoder:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html

What is the difference between `unknown_value` and `encoded_missing_value`?

Looking at source code it almost seems like they are being mixed in use.
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8c9c1f27b/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py#L1071

For example, for the code snippet below, changing the `encoded_missing_value` seems to not do anything.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
print()
ordinal_encoder_1 = OrdinalEncoder(
    categories = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]],
    handle_unknown="use_encoded_value",
    unknown_value=-1,
    #encoded_missing_value=-2
)
print(ordinal_encoder_1.fit_transform([[np.nan],["a"], ["a"], ['asdf'], [None], ["b"], ["c"]]))

1.1.1

[[-1.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [-1.]
 [-1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 2.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things.

**encoded_missing_value** is to specify how to encode the missing values. For example the np.NaN values. This is usefull when you don't specify the categories, or if one of your category is NaN. As you can see, by default the NaN values would be left as NaN. (None is not considered a missing value). For example:

```py
ordinal_encoder_1 = OrdinalEncoder(
    categories = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", np.NaN]],
    handle_unknown="use_encoded_value",
    unknown_value=-1,
    #encoded_missing_value=-2
)
print(ordinal_encoder_1.fit_transform([[np.nan],["a"], ["a"], ['asdf'], [None], ["b"], ["c"]]))
```

Output:

```py
[[nan]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [-1.]
 [-1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 2.]]
```

If we specify an encoded_missing_value:

```py
ordinal_encoder_1 = OrdinalEncoder(
    categories = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", np.NaN]],
    handle_unknown="use_encoded_value",
    unknown_value=-1,
    encoded_missing_value=-2
)
print(ordinal_encoder_1.fit_transform([[np.nan],["a"], ["a"], ['asdf'], [None], ["b"], ["c"]]))
```

Output:

```py
[[-2.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [-1.]
 [-1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 2.]]
```

**unknown_value** on the other hand is the new value given to all values not present in the categories (manually set categories, or auto-set categories).